# Changing value of parameter with gdb

Tags: disassembly, assembly, debugging, gdb, gcc

I have a file named exploit.c inside which:

```
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdio.h>

const char y1 = 'a';
const char y2 = 'b';
const char y3 = 'x';
const char y4 = 'y';
const char y5 = 'i';
const char y6 = 'j';

char x1 = 'f' ^ 'a';
char x2 = 'l' ^ 'b';
char x3 = 'a' ^ 'x';
char x4 = 'g' ^ 'y';
char x5 = 'y' ^ 'i';
char x6 = '-' ^ 'j';

int main() {
  bool c = false;
  if(c) { printf("The flag is: %c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c\n", x1 ^ y1, x2 ^ y2, x3 ^ y3, x4 ^
y4, x4 ^ y4, x5 ^ y5, x6 ^ y6, x1 ^ y1, x2 ^ y2, x3 ^ y3, x4 ^ y4); }
  return 0;
}
```

How can I print out the flag without changing the value of boolean but with gcc and gdb?

Comment: f^a^a  = f and so on flaggy-flag is spottable visually

Comment: Do you assume that you don't have the sources or debug symbols?

Comment: We assume that at least we have executable files

Comment: You'd also need to assume that it has been compiled _without_ optimisations; otherwise the executable would likely contain no remnants of the flag at all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was pretty easy one so I could do myself:)
We have exploit.c file where I need to debug it in order to get the flag with 'gcc'. I run the program with:

`gcc -g exploit.c -o exploit`

and got 'exploit' which is executable `exploit.c` file.
To launch the binary under a debugger - gdb

`gdb exploit`

We have `bool c = false;` on line 21, so put the break line on it:

```
break 21
```

Then: I changed the value of c by this command: `set variable c = true`
However, when I went to the  next line by “next” it become false again.
So I reset the value again: `set variable c = true` and then next button:
Yay, it printed out the flag:

```
(gdb) next

The flag is: flaggy-flag
23    return 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

The if statement is likely compiled into a conditional jump so you just need to step until the comparison and change the result. For example, if the jump is `je` or `jne`, you need to change the zero flag (ZF) to force the jump in the opposite direction.

For changing flags in GDB, see

https://stackoverflow.com/a/31339372

Another option is to change the instruction pointer ($rip or $eip) to the location which corresponds to the if body.